# Is UPDATE guaranteed to execute the SET assignments in the given order?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have a table `mytable` with columns `id`, `a`, `b` and there is a row with values `(123, 'foo', 'bar')`.

I perform this query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET b=a, a='boom' WHERE id=123
```

I'd expect the two assignments to be performed in the given order, and hence the resulting row to be `(123, 'boom', 'foo')`, but **is this guaranteed?**

Or is the order of execution undefined and hence theoretically possible that the optimizer for whatever reason decides to execute them in reverse order, which would end up with `(123, 'boom', 'boom')`?

MySQL documentation doesn't explicitly state that the assignments are executed in the order they appear in the query.

Comment: I would assume nothing, this may be something that changes in the future and I would hate it to be something that takes seconds to write code which assigns both values and comes back and stops working when a software update is done.

Answer (score 0):

[Mysql `UPDATE` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) says **no**

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.

So to be safe in the case you're updating one column with the value of another, i'd split the `UPDATE` statement into a separate query:

```
-- do all the fixed value updates here
UPDATE mytable SET a='boom', x='whatever' WHERE id=123; 
-- do "relational" updates here, after the values have been updated
UPDATE mytable SET b=a                    WHERE id=123;
```

Comment: If you do that in a multi-user environment you need to worry about race conditions.